# Measuring a balanced matching network

Tags: rf, wireless, impedance-matching

I'm working with a Silicon Labs EFR32G12 Wireless MCU and I'm following their design guides for developing the matching network for the device. However, I saw that in one of their design notes ([here](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/an930.1-efr32-series-1.pdf)), they mention measuring the actual performance of the matching network and they do this by soldering a pigtailed connector to the tx pin of the device. However, the device uses a balanced output scheme which is converted via a balun to an unbalanced signal. **How are they properly measuring the s parameters of the network even though they are only connected to one side of the balanced output?** They mention that "The reference plane of the S-parameter measurements is shifted to the TX pin" but I'm not quite sure if that's relevant to my question.

Here is the relevant section from the design note linked above:
[image: Design note]

Additionally, here's the topology of their matching network:

[image: Matching network]

Answer (score 0):

Measuring through the TRX pin, is a perfectly correct way of doing it.

You are right, the outputs and inputs of your RF - MCU are balanced, but part of the numerous components between the MCU and the coaxial connector are a BALUN. Which is used to convert from BAlanced to UNbalanced. This is a two way structure. i.e which works in both directions.

I think that the components used to make the BALUN are those highlighted below :

[image]

You can find on this website a BALUN calculator, and the topology used to make the conversion.

[BALUN CALCULATOR](https://leleivre.com/rf_lcbalun.html)

[image]